# MIME Type Error - Deploying a React App to Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment

I deployed an react app on heroku and it's not working anymore.

This [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLXrl.jpg) is happening

I thought that it happened because some of the enviroment variables wasn't passed to heroku. But it looks to be related to stylesheet.

Error Message:

```
Refused to apply style from 'https://twobudget.herokuapp.com/2budget/static/css/2.e15833e6.chunk.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
2.211252ea.chunk.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
main.a8362adb.chunk.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
2.211252ea.chunk.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
main.a8362adb.chunk.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
(index):1 Refused to apply style from 'https://twobudget.herokuapp.com/2budget/static/css/2.e15833e6.chunk.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

My Repository: https://github.com/LauraBeatris/2budget

Comment: It seems to me that the `homepage` property in your package.json file is pointing to the wrong url. Try changing the `homepage` prop. Specifically the `/2budget/` bit. Try removing it.

Comment: Thank you so much! now it's working, the old deploy that i did was with ghpages so i forgot about the homepage property at package.json